# Python in Cygwin

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin

I would like to know the difference in

1. installing Python, Paramiko packages in Cygwin and
2. Python is already installed in my Windows PC. I have installed Cygwin too (but without Python package) and in Cygwin terminal I do the following:

   $echo "PATH=\$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Python27" >> .bash_profile
   then,
   source .bash_profile (after doing this I am able to run a Python script from cygwin terminal).

If the steps in point number 2 works good, then still do I need to install python packages from a Cygwin mirror site ? If I have not done it, then what I might miss while running Python through Cygwin ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to do so. In fact, CYGWIN will inherit the PC's PATH, plus with virtual PATH, you can input "echo $PATH" in CYGWIN and input "PATH" and the windows console, you could find that CYGWIN has more PATH setting than the windows.  However, as you already overwrite the bash_profile, so it might not looks as what I said.
**Besides, the most significant difference is that most of the CYGWIN executable files depends on CYGWIN.dll, while the typically windows files don't.**

Answer (score 0):

To use Python in Cygwin, you add this line to `.bash_profile` file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/virtualenv/python2.7/Scripts
```

Hope for helps.

Comment: The `.bash_profile` file in `C:\cygwin\home\[username]`
If use Django, add  `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/cygdrive/c/virtualenv/python2.7/Lib/site-packages`
In this case, I use virtualenv

Comment: How can you do this from the cywing terminal?